# How to use a certain keyboard layout from emacs as Ubuntu keyboard layout

Tags: input-method, keyboard-layout

Good day,

I would like to use a certain keyboard layout outside of emacs, namely french-keyboard yet unfortunately I am not able to locate the definition of the keyboard layout. My question is as following:

1. Where (which emacs file and where is it physically location) can I find the definition of xyz keyboard layout?
2. What would be the most comfortable way to (here the question would overlap with superuser forum) use this layout as a general Ubuntu layout?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input method you mention is defined at `lisp/leim/quail/latin-post.el`.  You can take a look [here](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/lisp/leim/quail/latin-post.el#n1624).

As for your other question, you need to configure the input method on the level of your window system (Xorg or Wayland).  Perhaps you can define a custom one, if not available.   Or you could use EXWM and let Emacs manage the input method.